# How do I make a GUI like Popcorn Time?

Tags: c#, java, objective-c, c, user-interface

I am curious as to how one can go about creating a GUI in a similar manner to the popular Popcorn Time application? I have been learning Java, C, C++, and a tiny bit of Objective-C and I have no clue how to make my GUI look any better than that of Java's Swing framework. There seems to be a very limited level of style associated with these default layout frameworks, without getting very advanced with styling.

Is there a framework which will allow me to create better GUIs with Java without spending too much time on it? I'd like to focus on core functionality, but would also like my application to look a tad bit better than Java Swing.

Here is the type of GUI I'd like to create:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6Nmg.jpg

Comment: In short, attention to detail

Comment: Popcorn Time was created with pure HTML5+CSS+JS. They use node.js to run outside of a browser. There are many advantages: its platform independent, its a well know language (JS), and so on. The downside: its more slow than a native app (so slow as a Java app). If you like this approach, I suggest to you use a framework like atom-shell, created by the GitHub staff. A simple "Hello World" with this framework: https://github.com/atom/atom-shell/blob/master/docs/tutorial/quick-start.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with creating simple native GUI's, before attempting "beautiful" GUI's.

Since you told that you have an understanding in C++.
I would suggest you to learn Qt framework, which is based on C++.
I have been designing GUI's in Qt for over a year now, and occasionally i have used [Qt-stylesheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html)
to theme certain GUI elements.

After you become familar in Qt, you can find that there is openGL, QML , javascript and other support available, to create more customized GUI's, although i have not used them.

[Get started](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/gettingstarted.html) , with this simple notepad [app](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/gettingstartedqt.html) !